# MFC: What is guaranteed to be called after CWnd::OnCreate()?

Tags: winapi, mfc

Since `WM_SHOWWINDOW` (`OnShowWindow`) won't always be called per API docs, where do I process startup items that needs all `CTreeView`/`CListView`/etc.. of a `CSplitterWnd()` inside the `CMainFrame` populated?   I can't do in `OnCreate()` since the `OnInitialUpdate()` for the `CTreeView`/`CListView` come after that.

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding my own method `CMainFrame::OnAfterCreate()` which is called inside `CWinApp::InitInstance()` after the `CSigneDocTemplate` is created.

Comment: You are using the wrong tool. It sounds like you're re-inventing the Doc-View-Architecture inside your `CMainFrame` window. That's not how things are designed to work. Use a `CView` instead. It's [c'tor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cview-class#cview) has the following guarantees: *"The framework calls the constructor when a new frame window is created or a window is split. Override the [OnInitialUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cview-class#oninitialupdate) member function to initialize the view after the document is attached."*

Comment: I can't do it on OnInitialUpdate, has to be done later (using csplitterwnd where all related .  Anyway, the method I'm using works great.